# PHP function file_exists not working when using .htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, file-exists

I am using following in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^shopping-bag/?$ shoppingbag.php [L,QSA]
```

This changes the url

> http://www.domain.com/foldername/shoppingbag.php

to

> www.domain.com/foldername/shopping-bag/

All my content is placed in

> /www/foldername/

I fixed all the css and js files by declaring a global variable with value `http://www.domain.com/foldername/` and place this variable before the path of css and js files. Since file_exists won't work on a URL I tried doing the following

> ../uploads/image.jpg

The actual path of the image file is

> /www/foldername/uploads/image.jpg

I tried doing

```
var_dump(../uploads/image.jpg)
```

on

> http://www.domain.com/foldername/shopping-bag/

but didn't work. And I don't want to use `<base href="">`

Comment: What about `<base href="http://www.domain.com/foldername/">` ?

Comment: I think that part didn't show up without code tag. I don't want to use base href

Comment: `I fixed all the css ` is also not the best way, but it was just a comment from me :)

Comment: Oh I am sorry but I didn't mean to offend you. I was just saying I don't want to use base href because of some issues I am having because of it

Comment: Test in Chrome dev tool with caching disabled and check in Networking tab what are 404 URLs you get for css/js/images.

Comment: No problem, i didn't felt offended. Sometimes i just want give little directions, hint and so on. Hopefully you get it to work :-)

Comment: No comment on either answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you've changed PHP's current working directory with something like `chdir( $someDir )`, all file system functions should basically behave relative to the current script's directory.

In your case `file_exists( 'uploads/image.jpg' )` or `file_exists( './uploads/image.jpg' )` (note the single dot, meaning current directory) should therefore return `true`, if the file actually exists in the location you said it exists.

Note that `<base href="">` is irrelevant to the PHP script, because PHP is a **server-side** language, while `<base>` is a **client-side** HTML element.

To get a better understanding of the distinction between server-side and client-side (programming), have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13840431/165154), for instance.

Furthermore, unless you meant to demonstrate something different, `var_dump(../uploads/image.jpg)` will not output anything meaningful. You can't use `var_dump()` like that, but perhaps you were already aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

`foldername/shoppingbag.php` is the file you're running and `foldername/uploads/image.jpg` is the file it's interested in. The relative path should just be `uploads/image.jpg`.

What does this give?

```
var_dump('uploads/image.jpg');
```